# Searchlogic cannot sort search result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, searchlogic

Imagine a code:

```
search = Project.search(
  :title_or_description_or_child_name_or_child_age_or_inspiration_or_decorating_style_or_favorite_item_or_others_like_any => keys,
  :galleries_id_like_any => @g,
  :styles_id_like_any => @st,
  :tags_like_any => @t
)
```

search.all returns the rows correctly.

But search.descend_by_views returns nil.

Is this gem buggy? What else should I use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not working with `search.descend_by_views` but this should work:

```
search = Post.descend_by_views.search(
  :title => ...
  ...
)
```

Instead of search, you could also use scopes for everything else too:

```
Post.title_or_anything_like_any(keys).galleries_id_like_any(@g)...descend_by_views.all
```